# BouncyCastle Change KeySpec for AT_SIGNATURE

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, bouncycastle, private-key

I found a great example of using BouncyCastle's C# API for generating a CA cert and a self-signed certificate.

However, i need a KEYSPEC = 2 (At_Signature for CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID) and not a Keyspec of 0. Which this code currently provides:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


//Downloaded using nuget, source: http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/
//Library is open-source.

namespace CertificateToolLibrary
{
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X9;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Generators;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Prng;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Math;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509.Extension;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;

public class X509Certificate2Builder
{
    public string SubjectName
    { set { _subjectName = value; } }

    public string SubjectAlternativeName
    { set { _subjectAlternativeName = value; } }

    public string IssuerName
    { set { _issuerName = value; } }

    public AsymmetricAlgorithm IssuerPrivateKey
    { set { _issuerPrivateKey = value; } }

    public X509Certificate2 Issuer
    {
        set
        {
            _issuer = value;
            _issuerName = value.IssuerName.Name;
            if (value.HasPrivateKey)
                _issuerPrivateKey = value.PrivateKey;
        }
    }

    public int? KeyStrength
    { set { _keyStrength = value ?? 2048; } }

    public DateTime? NotBefore
    { set { _notBefore = value; } }

    public DateTime? NotAfter
    { set { _notAfter = value; } }

    public bool Intermediate
    { set { _intermediate = value; } }

    private string _subjectName;
    private string _subjectAlternativeName;
    private X509Certificate2 _issuer;
    private string _issuerName;
    private AsymmetricAlgorithm _issuerPrivateKey;
    private int _keyStrength = 2048;
    private DateTime? _notBefore;
    private DateTime? _notAfter;
    private bool _intermediate = true;

    public X509Certificate2 Build()
    {
        // Generating Random Numbers
        var randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
        var random = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);

        // The Certificate Generator
        var certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

        // Serial Number
        var serialNumber = BigIntegers.CreateRandomInRange(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.ValueOf(long.MaxValue), random);
        certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(serialNumber);

        // Signature Algorithm
        certificateGenerator.SetSignatureAlgorithm("SHA512WithRSA");

        // Issuer and Subject Name
        certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(new X509Name(_issuerName ?? _subjectName));
        certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(new X509Name(_subjectName));

        //Subject Alternative Name
        if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(_subjectAlternativeName)))
        {
            //Here we signify ip address instead of DNS SAN. This could be condition upon further development.
            GeneralNames subjectAltName = new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(GeneralName.IPAddress, _subjectAlternativeName));
            certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectAlternativeName, false, subjectAltName);
        }

        // Authority Key Identifier
        if (_issuer != null)
        {
            var authorityKeyIdentifier = new AuthorityKeyIdentifierStructure(DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(_issuer));
            certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.AuthorityKeyIdentifier.Id, false, authorityKeyIdentifier);

            //var subjectKeyIdentifier = new SubjectKeyIdentifier(DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(_issuer));
            //certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectKeyIdentifier.Id, false, subjectKeyIdentifier);
            //certificateGenerator.addExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectKeyIdentifier.Id, false, new SubjectKeyIdentifierStructure( keyPair.getPublic()));
        }

        // Basic Constraints - certificate is allowed to be used as intermediate.
        certificateGenerator.AddExtension( X509Extensions.BasicConstraints, false, new BasicConstraints(_intermediate));


        // Valid For
        certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(_notBefore ?? DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-1));
        certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(_notAfter ?? DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddYears(3));


        //Key Usage(s) don't set for CA cert, just the SSL cert.
        if (_subjectName != "CN=Bla Certificate Authority")
        {
            certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.KeyUsage, true, new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.DigitalSignature | KeyUsage.KeyEncipherment));
            var usages = new[] { KeyPurposeID.IdKPServerAuth, KeyPurposeID.IdKPClientAuth};
            certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage.Id, false, new ExtendedKeyUsage(usages));
        }


        // Subject Public Key
        var keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(random, _keyStrength);
        var keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);

        var subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
        var issuerKeyPair = _issuerPrivateKey == null
            ? subjectKeyPair
            : DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(_issuerPrivateKey);

        certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(subjectKeyPair.Public);

        //Add the subject key identifier for the SSL Certficate
        if (_subjectName != "CN=Bla Certificate Authority")
        {
            certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectKeyIdentifier, false, new SubjectKeyIdentifierStructure(subjectKeyPair.Public));
        }

        // selfsign certificate
        var certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(issuerKeyPair.Private, random);

        // merge into X509Certificate2
        return new X509Certificate2(certificate.GetEncoded())
        {
            PrivateKey = ConvertToRsaPrivateKey(subjectKeyPair)
        };
    }

    private static AsymmetricAlgorithm ConvertToRsaPrivateKey(AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair)
    {
        var keyInfo = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(keyPair.Private);
        var seq = (Asn1Sequence)Asn1Object.FromByteArray(keyInfo.PrivateKey.GetDerEncoded());
        if (seq.Count != 9)
            throw new PemException("malformed sequence in RSA private key");

        var rsa = new RsaPrivateKeyStructure(seq);
        var rsaparams = new RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters(rsa.Modulus, rsa.PublicExponent, rsa.PrivateExponent, rsa.Prime1, rsa.Prime2, rsa.Exponent1, rsa.Exponent2, rsa.Coefficient);

        return DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(rsaparams);



    }
}
```

}

I can't find any online examples of how to modify the keyspec to digital signature. I realize it should happen on the private key side, but there just aren't any examples out there, at least in using the bouncycastle code, specifically in the c# examples.

I figure one could use the rsaparams like cspparams in native c# code, but i just can't find anything on it.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the **[KeyUsage](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/KeyUsage.html)** constants class

I think you want to use **[KeyUsage.keyEncipherment](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/constant-values.html#org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.KeyUsage.keyEncipherment)**

Comment: yeah if you look in my example, i'm using both.

Comment: certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.KeyUsage, true, new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.DigitalSignature | KeyUsage.KeyEncipherment));
    var usages = new[] { KeyPurposeID.IdKPServerAuth, KeyPurposeID.IdKPClientAuth};
            certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage.Id, false, new ExtendedKeyUsage(usages));

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14025596)

Comment: @maazza Valid point - thanks - will keep that in mind for all future answers and will update when time permits. Mumbles76 - you have the OR'd value, did you try only keyEncipherment?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that i was on a desktop developing, and this keyspec was set to 0. However, when i ran my tool on a 2012 server, the keyspec was set to 1. I'm all set.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static AsymmetricAlgorithm ToDotNetKey(RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters privateKey)
    {
        var cspParams = new CspParameters
        {
            ProviderName = "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider",
            ProviderType = 24,
            KeyContainerName = KEY_CONTAINER_NAME,
            KeyNumber = (int)KeyNumber.Signature,
            Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore
        };

        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

        RSAParameters parameters = new RSAParameters
        {
            Modulus = privateKey.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            P = privateKey.P.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            Q = privateKey.Q.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            DP = privateKey.DP.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            DQ = privateKey.DQ.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            InverseQ = privateKey.QInv.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            D = privateKey.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            Exponent = privateKey.PublicExponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned()
        };

        rsaProvider.ImportParameters(parameters);

        return rsaProvider;
    }
```

So just to add another answer here, i was able to force keyspec=2 AT_SIGNATURE using this snippet. But it's currently experiencing issues with signing. Just wanted to throw it out there for other to potentially lead them in the right direction.